# openLdap for windows and phpldapadmin

Tags: windows-xp, openldap, ldap

I'm having a problem connecting all of this. I'm new to Ldap and after failing to install all of this on Ubuntu 10.04. I'm trying to set it up on my local PC.

1. I installed OpenLdap for windows
   http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx,
2. Enabled the php5.3.1 extension for ldap
   (c:\xampp\php\ext\php_ldap.dll) in
   php.ini
3. Copied the ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll to Windows\System32 &
   Windows\System (Windows XP)
4. Set the password generated by c:\Program
   Files\OpenLDAP\slappasswd.exe in
   c:\Program Files\OpenLDAP\slapd.conf
   (rootpw {SSHA}hash)
5. run the  c:\Program Files\OpenLDAP\slapd.exe
6. Install phpldapadmin and call https:// 127.0.0.1 / phpldapadmin/

when I enter the credentials i get **Invalid credentials (49) for user** and in openldap.log i get

> could not stat config file
>   "%SYSCONFDIR%\slapd.conf": No such
>   file or directory (2)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution to the error message you are getting is pretty straight forward.

You need to create the slapd.conf file and put it in the directory corresponding to `%SYSCONFDIR%`. OpenLDAP for Windows should come shipped with example files. They may even be located in the directory mentionned previously under a slightly different name such as slapd.conf.example